# Flattening attributes of nested XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to flatten a tree of nested XML elements by combining the values of an attribute using XSLT.  For instance, if I have the following input:

```
<node value="a">
    <node value="b">
        <node value="c">
            <node value="d">
            </node>
        </node>
        <node value="e">
            <node value="f">
            </node>
            <node value="g">
                <node value="h">
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

Then these would be the "flattened" results I would like to be able to get:

```
a/b/c/d
a/b/e/f
a/b/e/g/h
```

All I currently have been able to achieve is outputting a record only on the most deeply nested occurrences of node "node" with the "value" attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node[@value]">
        <xsl:if test="not(descendant::node[@value])">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you may have gathered from my description and the `xsl:if` test, a potential complication is that some instances of the "node" element may not have the "value" attribute and so this must be explicitly checked.  How can I update this stylesheet to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2 or 3 it becomes

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="descendant::node[@value and not(descendant::node[@value])]!string-join(ancestor-or-self::node/@value, '/')" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVh/0

With XSLT 1 I would use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::node[@value and not(descendant::node[@value])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::node/@value"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@value">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">/</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVh/1

Comment: This helped me reach a solution that seems to be working (using your second approach since `xsltproc` is limited to XSLT 1.0), but I had to modify it a bit first.  As is, it works for the immediate example, but afaik fails to allow me to retain access to any other attributes of the respective "node" elements I may like to process.  I had to push the attribute template's `value-of` back into the node template (now needing `last()` in `apply-templates`) and put the delimiter/newline within a choose block based on another "am I the last descendant" test (`position()` didn't seem to work anymore).

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper etiquette here is - should I just leave the modification as a comment here for future readers that share that need, accept the answer, and walk away, or should I update the question and let you similarly update the answer...?

Comment: I am afraid your problem description does not show any other attributes at all and does not explain that and where you want to output them. In a template matching any attribute of an element, like the `@value`, you can of course navigate to `../@foo` to select the `foo` attribute of the same element.

Comment: If you want to process the `node` elements twice instead of processing the `value` attributes then you can use a mode e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::node/." mode="atts"/>` and then output e.g. `<xsl:template match="node" mode="atts"><xsl:if test="position() > 1">/</xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="concat(@value, ',', @foo)"/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: A simple, borderline hello world style input for me is 60k lines long, so I was merely attempting to create a minimal example that got straight to the specific problem I was dealing with.  For posterity, the modification I originally made to your answer looked like this: <xsl:template match="node[@value]"><xsl:apply-templates select="(ancestor::node[@value])[last()]"/><do-other-stuff-here><xsl:value-of select="@value"/><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="not(descendant::node[@value])"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>/</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:template>

Comment: Having just started trying to figure out how to use XSLT, I was not aware that I could do something like `../@foo` and I haven't messed with the mode stuff you demonstrated.  It does look like it could be more to the point and looks a little less like a hack than what I was doing.  I'll try it out myself shortly.

Comment: It looks pretty clean, even though I'm still not clear on what makes `position()` work or not, and more importantly, whether the traversal order of the `ancestor-or-self` axis is guaranteed to preserve the tree hierarchy.  The documentation I've found just seems to refer to it as a node-set.